# jQuery Code Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I downloaded a code for a website tour from:
http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/.

I then wanted to integrate it to my own webpage. However there is a problem. The problem is, that the script uses jQuery 1.4.4. However there are some other elements on my webpage, which need the newer version of jQuery.

The old script uses a function "live", which is no longer supported in the newer versions of jQuery. After doing some research I found this page - http://api.jquery.com/live/ and I modified the code based on the instructions there.

The problem is solved only partially. Before it just gave an error and did nothing. After replacing "live" with "on", the script now works, but not as it should. The tooltips are not displayed as they should be and I tried various things, but everything unsuccessful.

So I would very much appreciate anyone´s help.

Here is the original version, which uses the old jQuery and works properly:
http://brzezina.cz/meteo/WebsiteTour/index.html

Here is the new version with the new version of jQuery, which however does not work as it should - try starting the guide and you will see the problem - the tooltips are not displayed next to their elements, but instead show on the top of the page.
http://brzezina.cz/meteo/WebsiteTour/new.html

The changes I made in the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

replaced with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
$('#activatetour').live('click',startTour);
$('#canceltour').live('click',endTour);
$('#endtour').live('click',endTour);
$('#restarttour').live('click',restartTour);
$('#nextstep').live('click',nextStep);
$('#prevstep').live('click',prevStep);
```

replaced with

```
$(document).on('click','#activatetour',startTour);
$(document).on('click','#canceltour',endTour);
$(document).on('click','#endtour',endTour);
$(document).on('click','#restarttour',restartTour);
$(document).on('click','#nextstep',nextStep);
$(document).on('click','#prevstep',prevStep);
```

I made no other changes and the new version shows no errors in the console, so I really do not have a clue where the problem is now.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the [migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) library, but that's not really supported for jQuery versions that old, but should restore live() so you can just try it and see if works. Other than that, it seems like a bad idea to use a plugin that old.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the Javascript that is the problem, its your css. You need to add position fixed to the tooltip. Also it seems the tooltips are below the overlay which can be fixed with z-indexing higher than the overlay. If you add the following css to your tooltips they will look much closer to the ones in the actual demo

```
position: fixed,
z-index: 101,
padding: 20p,
border-radius: 3px
```

so it would look like this:

```
var $tooltip = $('<div>',{
    id : 'tour_tooltip',
    'class' : 'tooltip', //changed className to 'class'
    html : '<p>'+step_config.text+'</p><span class="tooltip_arrow"></span>'
}).css({
    'display': 'none',
    'background-color' : bgcolor,
    'color' : color,
    'position': 'fixed',
    'z-index': 101,
    'padding': 20 + 'px',
    'border-radius': 3 + 'px'
});
```

Comment: you could move the position and padding and border radius to your css declaration for .tooltip too, which is better, the least amount of inline code is best

Comment: thanx a lot, your solution works, but why is it not loading this class from the css as it did before? I have these properties in a class "tooltip" in a separate css file, which was loaded in the original version.

Comment: see my edit to the example above, you were using className and it should be class, be sure to add quotes around class, it is a protected word in javascript and will error if you do not

Comment: thanks a lot, it now all works apart from one last thing. When the tooltip is outside of the current view of the screen, the script scrolled down to it, now it doesnt do that, any clue why?

Comment: i wouldn't be able to properly debug without the tooltips being in the proper place, right now they are all still at the top so i can't tell. anyway, you should really spend a lot of time trying to figure it out on your own first, it will help you increase your debugging ability, watch some tutorials on debugging and give it a shot. if still no luck update the example site and pose a new question here